# Flawed OTP system while OTP verification

Tags: java, spring-boot, totp

I am creating an app where user has to verify their email address once they are registered. This done via an OTP which is send once the users has hit the registration API. If the OTP is valid then we confirm the registration else we remove the user.
When I register a user I also create an OTP object which I associate with the user.
For example,

```
class Otp{
.
.
.
private User user;

// setter and getter
.
.
}
```

So here is a scenario. Let's say a user *A* has registered itself but has not verified themselves yet. Now some other person hits the verification API and by chance sends the same OTP which has been received by user *A* and user *A* gets registered. Now the chances for this to happen are very low because my OTP length is going be 7-8 characters long, but not zero.
I see this as a security flaw. Are all the OTP systems flawed like this or I am doing something wrong. If yes can someone suggest a good design for an OTP system.

Comment: had the same question lol. glad you asked it before. it was easy with email verification links (or magic links) but with email verification codes (or otps), this problem shows up. i think another way is to let otp's expire. i'm also [rate-limiting my api route](https://github.com/deadcoder0904/nextjs-rate-limit) so anyone who tries to brute-force is blacklisted or slowed down by my api depending on their browser fingerprint or ip.

Answer (score 1):

What "by chance" do you have in mind? If your application hands out OTPs, you can limit their validity (e.g. 24 or 48 hours) and keep a list of OTPs to avoid re-use, or use a deterministic crypto algorithm to generate unique but unguessable passwords.

If you think of user B just guessing/brute forcing OTPs, the security implications are just with any brute force attacks, you're probably even more safe since your OTP is truly random generated and would not be susceptible to dictionary attacks.

Since the OTP would only be valid for user A's account anyway, user B would have to guess that correctly as well, which reduces the probability to something that can be safely ignored.

Comment: Yes yes got it. Thats what i wanted to ask. I thought other OTP services were more secure or something. And by chance I ment, let's say user *A* has otp "aWer34" and user *B* has otp "sWer34", so by chance he pressed 'a' instead of 's' and will register user *A*, which is I know not possible, but the chances are not zero either.

Comment: The chances are low enough with 7-8 character OTPs that you can safely ignore them, unless you protect access to multi-million dollar bank accounts. Even my banking card is only protected by a 4 digit pin :-)